# customize carousel help required

Tags: css, html, user-interface, carousel

I need suggestions in building below UI. It's a carousel like structure where active over is highlighted in green and we can still see next overs disabled or gray color.

I have researched for this for ex. Can I make use of any carousel to fit this design but can't seem to come to any conclusion. Thought of slider also but did not see that fitting this design.

Guys, do you have any suggestion or pointers to get me started here. I do not need code; just want a startup point. So far I am stuck with carousel or slider. 
I understand this might not be most constructive question on SO but any pointers will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you didn't provide any information about what should happen when you click on these items. If I understand correctly, you are looking for a carousel supporting your own pager design. If this is correct, you must add the pager markup first, after that you can use any carousel that supports slide switching methods. Then you can add click event listener to your pager items and call switching method in the listener, setting by that a new slide corresponding to the pager element index.

For example, you can try [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), as it has .slickGoTo() method, which you can use to switch slides programmatically. You can also try to customize slick's default pager, but it might be not so easy or even impossible at all.